# Remove/undef a class method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

You can dynamically define a class method for a class like so:

```
class Foo
end

bar = %q{def bar() "bar!" end}
Foo.instance_eval(bar)
```

But how do you do the opposite: ***remove/undefine*** a class method? I suspect Module's `remove_method` and `undef_method` methods might be able to be used for this purpose, but all of the examples I've seen after Googling for hours have been for removing/undefining *instance* methods, not class methods. Or perhaps there's a syntax you can pass to `instance_eval` to do this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

Foo.bar    # => bar

class <<Foo
  undef_method :bar
end
# or
class Foo
  singleton_class.undef_method :bar
end

Foo.bar    # => undefined method `bar' for Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

When you define a class method like Foo.bar, Ruby puts it Foo's singleton class.  Ruby can't put it in Foo, because then it would be an instance method.  Ruby creates Foo's singleton class, sets the superclass of the singleton class to Foo's superclass, and then sets Foo's superclass to the singleton class:

```
Foo -------------> Foo(singleton class) -------------> Object
        super      def bar             super
```

There are a few ways to access the singleton class:

- `class <<Foo`,
- `Foo.singleton_class`,
- `class Foo; class << self` which is commonly use to define class methods.

Note that we used `undef_method`, we could have used `remove_method`. The former prevents any call to the method, and the latter only removes the current method, having a fallback to the super method if existing. See [Module#undef_method](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) for more information.

Comment: I would have thought it'd be possible without using the Eigenclass, at least in 1.9.

Comment: @Andrew, Perhaps so.  Alas, I do not know it.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ruby1.9.3.  I was still able to call the removed method.

Comment: @joseph.hainline - That's interesting!  I just confirmed that the above works in MRI 1.8.3-p374, MRI 1.9.3-p484, MRI 2.0.0-p247, and MRI 2.1.0.  Are you perhaps doing something different, either when removing the method, or when calling it, or perhaps using a non-MRI Ruby?

Comment: @joseph.hainline - If you have the method in super class, the method is still callable after you call removed_method. You can use undef_method to prevent it.

Answer (score 19):

This also works for me (not sure if there are differences between undef and remove_method):

```
class Foo
end

Foo.instance_eval do
  def color
    "green"
  end
end

Foo.color # => "green"

Foo.instance_eval { undef :color }

Foo.color # => NoMethodError: undefined method `color' for Foo:Class
```

Comment: This worked for me. I called it on an object, and it only removed it at the object level. Foo.new.instance_eval { undef :color } works too.

Comment: removed_method removes method of receiver class where as undef_method removed all methods from inherited class including receiver class.

Answer (score 8):

You can remove a method in two easy ways. The drastic

```
Module#undef_method( )
```

removes all methods, including the inherited ones. The kinder

```
Module#remove_method( )
```

removes the method from the receiver, but it
leaves inherited methods alone.

See below 2 simple example  -

**Example 1 using *undef_method***

```
class A 
    def x
        puts "x from A class"
    end
end

class B < A
    def x
        puts "x from B Class"
    end
    undef_method :x
end

obj = B.new
obj.x
```

result  -
main.rb:15:in 
`': undefined method`x' for # (NoMethodError)

**Example 2 using *remove_method***

```
class A 
    def x
        puts "x from A class"
    end
end

class B < A
    def x
        puts "x from B Class"
    end
    remove_method :x
end

obj = B.new
obj.x
```

Result -
$ruby main.rb

x from A class

Answer (score 6):

I guess I can't comment on Adrian's answer because I don't have enough cred, but his answer helped me.

What I found: `undef` seems to completely remove the method from existence, while `remove_method` removes it from that class, but it will still be defined on superclasses or other modules that have been extened on this class, etc.

Comment: In Ruby 2.4 it looks to be `undef_method` now.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to remove method with name what calculate dinamically, you should use eigenclasses like:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

name_of_method_to_remove = :bar
eigenclass = class << Foo; self; end
eigenclass.class_eval do
  remove_method name_of_method_to_remove
end
```

this way is better than others answers, becouse here i used class_eval with block. As you now block see current namespace, so you could use your variables to remove methods dinamically

Answer (score -1):

Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo)

Comment: Doesn't that remove the whole class?

Comment: Technically this answer isn't inaccurate (i.e. this is, in fact, a way to remove class methods), since by removing class Foo it also removes all the class methods in Foo :P :P :P.

I mean, it's obviously not what the OP actually wants, but technically it's not *false*.

Other technically correct answers: 1) kill the containing Ruby process;
2) restart the OS; 3) throw the computer into a lake; 4) drop a nuclear bomb nearby; 5) trigger a supernova; 6) Wait for the heat death of the universe.