# Removing/undefining a class method that's included by another module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like to remove a class method that gets added to my class via the `include` function. For example:

```
class Foo
    include HTTParty

    class << self
      remove_method :get
    end
end
```

This doesn't work, it says "get" isn't a method on Foo. Basically, the "get" method is provided the HTTParty module and I'd like to remove it. I've tried several attempts with no luck. Things I've read/tried:

- [Removing/undefining a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079240/removing-undefining-a-class-method)
- http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/15408
- http://split-s.blogspot.com/2006/01/removing-methods-from-module.html

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to remove the `get` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `undef` instead of `remove_method`:

```
require 'httparty'

class Foo
  include HTTParty
  class << self
    undef :get
  end
end

Foo.get #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for Foo:Class
```

> Cancels the method definition. Undef can not appear in the method
>   body. By using undef and alias, the interface of the class can be
>   modified independently from the superclass, but notice it may be broke
>   programs by the internal method call to self.
>   http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#undef