# Ruby C API - how to remove class methods (specifically, new)?

Tags: c, ruby

I'm writing a Ruby binding to a C library. I want to remove the `new` method from some of my classes  - I'm creating objects with other class methods like `create` and `load` and the default implementation of `new` just leaves me with an invalid pointer (the objects of the class are just pointers to opaque structs).

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079240/removing-undefining-a-class-method) but

```
class Test
end

class <<Test
   remove_method :new
end
```

Just gave me

> > NameError: method `new' not defined in Class

And anyways I want to do it from C (and avoid `rb_eval_string`).

Answer (score 1):

The `new` method does 3 things:

- It calls `allocate`
- It calls `initialize`
- It returns the new object (and ignores the return value of initialize).

I don't think you can succesfully remove it. However making `new` private is fine:

```
class X

  def initialize(a,b)
    @a=a
    @b=b
  end

  private_class_method :new

  def X.create(x,y)
    new(x,y)
  end

end
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I be able to remove it? I'm not using it anyway (not within the class either).

Comment: So what's the reason that you create class not module?